# Avoiding for loop and data type errors in data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Hi I am working on data similar to the following:-

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Joy","Jane"),M1=c(10,40),M2=c(25,35),Choice=c("M1","M2")

    Name   M1   M2  Choice
1   Joy    10   25     M1
2   Jane   40   35     M2


for (i in (1:length(df[,1]))){
  df$Final[i] <- as.character(df[i,df$Choice[i]])
}

Output :-

    Name   M1   M2   Choice Final
1   Joy    10   25     M1   Joy
2  Jane    40   35     M2    40
```

This output is wrong and I found out that it is because **df$Choice[i]** returns factors and so I converted it to characters and got the right output.

```
for (i in (1:length(df[,1]))){
  df$Final[i] <- as.character(df[i,as.character(df$Choice[i])])
}

Output:- 

    Name   M1   M2 Choice Final
1    Joy   10   25     M1    10
2   Jane   40   35     M2    35
```

My question after all this is how can I perform the same manipulation on larger data sets avoiding the loop. If I use

```
df$Final <- as.character(df[,as.character(df$Choice)])  

Output:-


      Name   M1  M2   Choice     Final
1     Joy    10  25     M1     c(10, 40)
2     Jane   40  35     M2     c(25, 35)
```

This is not right.

Also I want to avoid getting in to using as.character every time on every calculation. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is using `dplyr` with `mutate` and `do`. You could `cbind` this column onto the original dataframe later if you want.

Essentially the idea is firstly you extract the index of the column that `df$Choice` is referring to, and then you can use `do` within `dplyr` to create a new dataframe with it indexed.

Full code:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Name=c("Joy","Jane"),M1=c(10,40),M2=c(25,35),Choice=c("M1","M2"))
df$Choice <- as.character(df$Choice)
nm <- names(df)

df1 <- df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(colIndex=which(nm == Choice)) %>%
  do(data.frame(Name=.$Name, Final=.[[.$colIndex]]))
```

Output

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

    Name Final
  <fctr> <dbl>
1    Joy    10
2   Jane    35
```

You can simply use something like: `df$Final <- df1$Final` to get the result you're after.

```
> df$Final <- df1$Final
> df
  Name M1 M2 Choice Final
1  Joy 10 25     M1    10
2 Jane 40 35     M2    35
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated need of `as.character()`, use `stringasFactors` argument in `data.frame()`:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Joy","Jane"), M1=c(10,40), M2=c(25,35), Choice=c("M1","M2"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Also, consider an lapply solution:

```
df$Final <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i,df$Choice[i]]))
```